# How to solve this inequality and sketch this graph?

Tags: inequality

[image]

I tried squaring and simplifying and got a solution set different to the one it says in the answer so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Also not sure how to sketch the graph any help?

Comment: For (a), use $|x| = x$ for $x \geq 0$, and $|x| =-x$, otherwise. For (b), choose points taking into account the suggestion presented in (a).

Answer (score 1):

[image]
$$3|x+1|-|x-4|<6\\$$when x>4 $$3(x+1)-(x-4)<6 $$so x<1.75 ,

when x<-1 $$ -3(x+1)+(x-4)<6 $$so x>-6.5

so answer is  $$-6.5<x<1.75 $$

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about solving a) is to consider the equation over different intervals to deal with the absolute signs. Note that $x+1$ is negative for $x<-1$ and $x-4$ is negative for $x<4$. Let's consider the equation for $x<-1$. Since $x+1$ and $x-4$ are negative for $x<-1$ then $|x+1|=-x-1$ and $|x-4|=-x+4$ when $x<-1$. Substituting these into the equation and solving for $x$ yields a solution of $-13/2<x<-1$. Repeating this procedure for the other necessary intervals will result in a full solution set.